# Laravel - Change pagination root url

Tags: laravel

I am building an `API Gateway` and I am having a small problem returning the pagination urls from a microservice to the `API Gateway`.

This is the current structure of my `API Gateway`:

[image: Microservice Arquitecture]

When I call the microservice, I can easily pass the paging parameters using the request data:

```php
HTTP::get('http://api.billing.microservice.test/v2/invoices', $request->all());
```

However, when I make a request for a microservice, it returns the requested data, but with the URL of the microservice:

```json
{
    "data": [
        # data returned from billing microservice with the billing API URL
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http://api.billing.microservice.test/v2/invoices?page=1",
        "last": "http://api.billing.microservice.test/v2/invoices?page=10",
        "prev": null,
        "next": "http://api.billing.microservice.test/v2/invoices?page=2"
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 10,
        "path": "http://api.billing.microservice.test/v2/invoices",
        "per_page": 30,
        "to": 30,
        "total": 300
    }
}
```

However I need the return to have the main `API URL`:

```json
{
    "data": [
        # data returned from billing microservice with the main API Address
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http://api.main.test/v2/invoices?page=1",
        "last": "http://api.main.test/v2/invoices?page=10",
        "prev": null,
        "next": "http://api.main.test/v2/invoices?page=2"
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 10,
        "path": "http://api.main.test/v2/invoices",
        "per_page": 30,
        "to": 30,
        "total": 300
    }
}
```

Has anyone had to do something similar? What is the best way to achieve the desired results? Do a replace using some kind of regex? Is there anything I can do inside the microservice?

Comment: You can use `->withPath()` on your paginated results: `$users = App\User::paginate(15); $users->withPath('custom/url');` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods ... If you want to have a completely different domain, you most likely need to create your own paginator

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem with a simple method that already exists:

```php
Model::paginate()->setPath('http://api.main.microservice.test/v2/invoices');
```

The result is:

```
{
    "data": [
        # data
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http://api.main.microservice.test/v2/invoices?page=1",
        "last": "http://api.main.microservice.test/v2/invoices?page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "path": "http://api.main.microservice.test/v2/invoices",
        "per_page": 30,
        "to": 3,
        "total": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

```php
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        #fix reverse proxy issues with paginator
        Paginator::currentPathResolver(function () {
            return config('app.url');
        });
    }
```

Simply do the above and you can change the `config('app.url')` to what you want, this will change the paginator base url.

Answer (score 0):

As Stanley's solution didn't work for me (it replaced the complete request URL with the new base URL ignoring the previous path), I came up with a different solution:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    // force the url() helper to use a different base URL
    URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    Paginator::currentPathResolver(function () {
        // generate a fully qualified URL based on the original request path
        return url(request()->path());
    });
}
```

This also fixes other URLs generated by Laravel to use the correct base URL (configured in `config('app.url')`).